# Network request going from which IP address

Tags: networking, proxy, tor

I am trying to see the concept of tor and prvoxy

```
import socks
import socket
def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

# patch the socket module
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection

import urllib2
res = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.google.com")
```

I started tor and [privoxy](https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/how-to-install-privoxy-and-combine-it-with-tor/),  now want to see that in last line, request to google going from which IP. how to look at this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check the public IP address would be to first make a HTTP request to a service like:

http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/

The same address would be seen by Google server if you make another HTTP request.